# WPF: Setting Focus To A Control Inside a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` that is bound to a datasource and generates several containers.  I am using code to ensure that only one of the containers is visible at any given time.  The containers use a `TemplateSelector` so the content of each container is different (which rules out finding the control by name).

I would like to set the keyboard focus to the first control in the currently visible container.  I have added an event handler to the `IsVisibleChanged` event for each container but when I access the `VisualTree` there are no children.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can only set focus on the child element after the child element itself has become visible.  One option is to find the child element you want to focus, then add a handler to its `IsVisibleChanged`.  In the handler, Focus the object and then remove the handler.

```
private void stackPanel1_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (stackPanel1.IsVisible)
    {
        UIElement elm = stackPanel1.Children[0];
        FrameworkElement fwe = (FrameworkElement)elm;
        fwe.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(fwe_IsVisibleChanged);
    }
}

void fwe_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement fwe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    fwe.IsVisibleChanged -= new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(fwe_IsVisibleChanged);
    Keyboard.Focus((IInputElement)sender);
}
```

Edit:
You should be able to access the Items collection in the IsVisibleChanged event handler.

```
<ItemsControl Name="sp1" IsVisibleChanged="sp1_IsVisibleChanged" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
</ItemsControl>
```

With this code:

```
void sp1_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(sp1.Items.Count);
}
```

Comment: My problem is finding the child element.  What I have is a ContentPresenter which should have the controls from whichever template was selected but it's visual tree appears to have no children.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some code which accesses the items collection.  I've tested this and it works - I realize it's different to what you are describing but I'd have thought the concept was the same.  Should I delete my answer so you have a better chance of getting a response?